# Date is displaying weird times in query?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I got this query here

```
db.query("SELECT developers.id, developers.name, absent.absentday, developers.selected, date.date FROM developers LEFT OUTER JOIN absent ON absent.absentName = developers.name LEFT OUTER JOIN date ON date.dateName = developers.name;",
        (err, result, fields) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                result_database = Object.values(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)));
                console.log("Result from all Database Rows", result_database);
                resultStatement();
            }
        })
```

I'm not finding anything weird to this query. But for some reason my dates are returned weirdly. What it should be

```
  {
    id: 57,
    name: 'tom hiddle',
    absentday: null,
    selected: 1,
    date: '2022-05-16'
  },
```

What I'm getting In return

```
  {
    id: 57,
    name: 'tom hiddle',
    absentday: null,
    selected: 1,
    date: '2022-05-15T22:00:00.000Z'
  },
```

The 2022-05-16 is turned into 15 from a day ago, also the time is being displayed for no reason. The date type is date. When I run my query in the database it returns the value normal as it should be.
Anyone that can help me here?

(Sorry I know there are other threads for this but I'm just wondering if there is a better solution for this? None of the answers work for me in the other threads)

Comment: Quite strange.  Any timezone difference?

Comment: What happens if you cast date as a date instead? Looks like the query is returning it as a datetime.

Comment: @AleixCC trying that but can't get it to work :/

Comment: SELECT CAST(date AS DATE) as a fact I know this is what I have to do, should I replace the small date into '2022-05-19' it would be converted. But I have to get multiple records with dates, so this is not possible. 

select cast(date AS DATE) doesn't work.

Comment: *What I'm getting In return* This is **NOT** MySQL output - it doesn't use and even doesn't know such datetime format. I think that this is node.js issue - it converts the date value to its own format and additionally adjusts it into client's time zone. Recommendation - return datetime column not as date but convert it to string datatype (`CAST(date.date AS CHAR)`).